# NullPointerException on calling the ProgressDialog()

Tags: android

I am calling one progressDialog on nonactivity class but when run the android app, App is crashing throwing this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference

This my code

```
private void showProgressDialogueArea() {
    if (null == progressDialogForArea) {
      initProgressDialogArea();
    }
    try {
      progressDialogForArea.show();
      progressDialogForArea.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog_custom);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Utils.logExceptionCrashLytics(e);
      Logger.logInfo("Exception", "Exception Occured");
    }
  }

  private void dissmisDialogueArea() {
    if (progressDialogForArea != null && progressDialogForArea.isShowing()) {
      try {
        progressDialogForArea.dismiss();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.logExceptionCrashLytics(e);
        Logger.logInfo("Exception", "Exception Occured");
      }
    }
  }

  private void initProgressDialogArea() {
    progressDialogForArea = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialogForArea.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialogForArea.setCancelable(false);
  }
```

Comment: I am not using any async Task here I am just calling one API for json response before that I want show the progressDialog and after that I have to hide the progressDialog.

Comment: no this is my non activity class if it's activity then I can pass activity reference but this is a non activity class.

Comment: from which activity are you passing context?

Comment: I am calling this API for other class not for Activity, I think getActivity(); will not work

Answer (score 1):

This is because the wrong context.
Pass the context in the constructor, and use this.

For example:

```
.
.
public void YourClass(Context c){
    this.c = c;
}
```

and when you call it:

```
Context c = getContext(); //depend on where you use it

YourClass yourObj = new YourClass(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, I think it will help

```
progressDialogForArea = new ProgressDialog(context.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: If not you should show how you pass context and use it.

Comment: marketPlace = new MarketPlace(context); This first class from where I am passing context to marketPlace = new MarketPlace(context); other MarketPlace class

Comment: did you initialized context before use like "Context context = getActivity();" if it si fragment